# Self signed ssl I created for localhost cannot be trusted even though I have already imported it to chrome

Tags: certificate, certificate-authority, openssl

I generated a certificate using ssl by running the script from the following link: https://gist.github.com/bjanderson/075fadfccdd12623ab935e57eff58eb4

The script ran just fine and I received all the expected files. I've imported the ca.crt to my chrome under the trusted root certification authorities but chrome still won't trust it.

I get the following errors:

```
Certificate - Subject Alternative Name missing
The certificate for this site does not contain a Subject Alternative Name extension containing a domain name or IP address.

Certificate - missing
This site is missing a valid, trusted certificate (net::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID).
```

How do i fix these two issues and get my chrome to trust my self signed certificate?

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> Certificate - Subject Alternative Name missing
> The certificate for this site does not contain a Subject Alternative Name
>                                              extension containing a domain name or IP address.
> ```

This mean:

- The *CN* don't match *ServerName*
- And the *X509v3 Subject Alternative Name* field don't too.

> ```
> Certificate - missing
> This site is missing a valid, trusted certificate (net::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID).
> ```

This mean:

Server could not be trusted, because no valid certificate was provided...
Ok, this would be solved when first error will be solved!

Think about the way (IP address or DNS name) you connect your server:

```
https://228.929.123.46/
```

or

```
https://mydomain.example.com/
https://127.0.0.1/
https://$HOSTNAME/
```

You could create cert with

- *`CN=228.929.123.46`* and add *`DNS.1=mydomain.example.com DNS.2=$HOSTNAME IP.1=127.0.0.1 DNS.3=other.domain.org DNS.`*...
- *`CN=127.0.0.1`* and add *`DNS.1=mydomain.example.com DNS.2=$HOSTNAME IP.1=228.929.123.46 DNS.3=other.domain.org DNS.`*...

But if on Internet, you'd better to whipe unfull hostname, localnet (192.168.x.x) and localip (127.x.x.x)!

- *`CN=228.929.123.46`* and add *`DNS.1=mydomain.example.com DNS.2=other.domain.org DNS.`*...

And use only DNS address or public ip to reach your server!

Have a look there,

- [Subject Alternative Name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subject_Alternative_Name) at wikipedia.org

Then to see how to do this...

- [Provide subjectAltName to OpenSSL directly on the command line](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/74345/15701) at security.stackexchange.com
- [Adding Subject Alternative Name (SAN) to a digital certificate](https://documentation.progress.com/output/ua/OpenEdge_latest/index.html#page/gscsv/adding-subject-alternative-name-(san)-to-a-digit.html) at documentation.progress.com
- [Generate ssl certificates with Subject Alt Names on OSX](https://gist.github.com/croxton/ebfb5f3ac143cd86542788f972434c96) at github.com/croxton

Comment: my https server is 127.0.0.1 which I already change instead of localhost when creating server.csr. can i put that in? or does it have to be https://127.0.0.1:8080 (8080 is port im running)

Comment: You could have only one CN, but as many *SAN* you want.

Comment: I still don't get what SAN does. Is it so that the certificates can be used by more than one places?

Comment: *`SAN`* mean *`Subject Alternative Name`*. as *`Alternative`* to ***`CN`***. So your ip address could figure eighter under *`CN`* **or** at any place in *`SAN`*.

Comment: Okay then, since I don't have a domain name do I just put in my IP address for SAN?

Comment: Or simply generate cert without *SAN*, but for ***Public IP***, then configure the *ServerName* directive in your web server!

Comment: @alexW, as *New contributor*, please consider *Accept* and/or *UpVote* in stackexchange websites! ;-)

Comment: Ah, and TCP port is not part of x509 by default. So no matter wich port you use!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95546/discussion-between-alexw-and-f-hauri).

Comment: 1. in 2019 SAN is required, it's not alternative. CN is optional. Domain used in URL must be in SAN for browser to validate. 2. You might need to put "ip:" instead of "dns:" in SAN.

Comment: Did you  restart your webserver once certs renewed?